# How do I unlock Shampoodle in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How do you unlock Shampoodle in *Animal Crossing New Leaf*?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Shampoodle#In_Animal_Crossing:_New_Leaf):

> It (*Shampoodle that is*) must first be unlocked by spending at least 10,000 Bells between the Able Sisters store or Kicks. Kicks must also be open for at least 7 days before construction begins. It takes 4 days for Shampoodle to be built.